# How to fix setOnItemClickListener inside ListView

Tags: android, listview, click, focus

I have a ListView which has more rows in it. Inside of rows I have two LinearLayouts (deleteItem and editItem) which has setOnClickListener on them. When I'm trying to click on deleteItem or editItem it works only at the second touch, i don't know why.. I've read some answers on stackoverflow but I couldn't find one answer to fix my problem..

This is the code:

```
 import org.json.JSONArray;

 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.LinearLayout;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.currencymeeting.adapters.GetAllMyCurrencyListViewAdapter;
 import com.currencymeeting.beans.User;
 import com.currencymeeting.connectors.DeleteCurrencyConnector;
 import com.currencymeeting.connectors.MyCurrencyConnector;
 import com.currencymeeting.controllers.MessageDialogController;
 import com.currencymeeting.controllers.VariableController;

public class MyCurrencyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private ListView getAllMyCurrencyListView;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private View view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_currency);

    this.dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyCurrencyActivity.this, MessageDialogController.PROGRESS_DIALOG_TITLE, MessageDialogController.PROGRESS_DIALOG_MESSAGE);
    this.getAllMyCurrencyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.getAllMyCurrencyListView);
    new GetMyCurrencyResults().execute(new MyCurrencyConnector());

    getAllMyCurrencyListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    MyCurrencyActivity.this.view = view;

                    final TextView itemID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemID);
                    final LinearLayout deleteItem = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.deleteItem);
                    final LinearLayout editItem = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.editItem);

                    deleteItem.setOnClickListener(
                            new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MyCurrencyActivity.this)
                                    .setMessage("Are you sure do you want to delete it?")
                                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

                                            String vid = itemID.getText().toString();
                                            String userId = ""+VariableController.getInstance().getUser().getId();

                                            new DeleteCurrencyTask().execute(userId, vid);
                                        }
                                     })
                                     .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                                            //do nothing
                                        }
                                     })
                                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                                    .show();
                                }

                            }
                            );

                    editItem.setOnClickListener(
                            new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EditCurrencyActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }

                            }
                            );

                }

            }
            );

    final LinearLayout menu = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu);

    menu.setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuLoggedActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
            );      
}

public void setListAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray){
    this.getAllMyCurrencyListView.setAdapter(new GetAllMyCurrencyListViewAdapter(jsonArray,this));
    this.dialog.dismiss();
};

private class GetMyCurrencyResults extends AsyncTask<MyCurrencyConnector,Void,JSONArray>{
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(MyCurrencyConnector... params) {
        User user = VariableController.getInstance().getUser();
        return params[0].getAllResults(user);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        setListAdapter(jsonArray);
    }

}

private class DeleteCurrencyTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]>{

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {

        boolean status = new DeleteCurrencyConnector().deleteTransaction(result[0],result[1]);
        LinearLayout itemViewId = (LinearLayout) MyCurrencyActivity.this.view.findViewById(R.id.itemViewID);
        if(status){
            new GetMyCurrencyResults().execute(new MyCurrencyConnector());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MyCurrencyActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Please, specify whats your problem: You don't want onItemClick fires or you want that if you click on linearlayout inside ListViewItem, do something diferent than onItemClick???

Comment: OP is quite clear that click only works on second time when it should work on first.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be caused by the way your program executes. You first thread your adapter initialization, and then your main thread starts attaching onclick listeners before your adapter initialization finishes. This means your listview will have a click listener but not the items in the adapter, and when you click the listview once

```
new GetMyCurrencyResults().execute(new MyCurrencyConnector());
```

this fires off in your DeleteCurrencyTask and sets the adapter again. To fix this try putting setOnClick initializaion in the post execute of your

```
private class GetMyCurrencyResults extends AsyncTask<MyCurrencyConnector,Void,JSONArray>{
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I realized why the event of deleteItem and editItem is called only on second click, because deleteItem and editItem clickListeners are atached only when getAllMyCurrencyListView.setOnItemClickListener (when I click on row) is called not when the code is loaded. So I guess I have to find another way to make these events